# pdf.js: Get the text colour

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I have a simple pdf file, containing the words "Hello world", each in a different colour.

I'm loading the PDF, like this:

```
PDFJS.getDocument('test.pdf').then( onPDF );

function onPDF( pdf )
{
    pdf.getPage( 1 ).then( onPage );
}

function onPage( page )
{
    page.getTextContent().then( onText );
}

function onText( text )
{   
    console.log( JSON.stringify( text ) );
}
```

And I get a JSON output like this:

```
{
    "items" : [{
            "str" : "Hello ",
            "dir" : "ltr",
            "width" : 29.592,
            "height" : 12,
            "transform" : [12, 0, 0, 12, 56.8, 774.1],
            "fontName" : "g_font_1"
        }, {
            "str" : "world",
            "dir" : "ltr",
            "width" : 27.983999999999998,
            "height" : 12,
            "transform" : [12, 0, 0, 12, 86.5, 774.1],
            "fontName" : "g_font_1"
        }
    ],
    "styles" : {
        "g_font_1" : {
            "fontFamily" : "serif",
            "ascent" : 0.891,
            "descent" : 0.216
        }
    }
}
```

However, I've not been able to find a way to determine the colour of each word. When I render it, it renders properly, so I know the information is in there somewhere. Is there somewhere I can access this?

Comment: Not that simple, the PDF spec defines two code paths for painting and text extraction. PDF.js is extracting text at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/core/evaluator.js#L886 and creates paint commands in different place. You can extend the former with a color info if needed (it might not be just a color)

Comment: Do you have an idea where it recovers the colour data? I might be able to hack something together for what I need

Comment: See http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf for several operators that control fill and stroke style, that includes gradients, patterns, and assignment via colorspace. Example of such handling at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/core/evaluator.js#L758

Comment: I believe, if any text(glyphs) in the PDF has been set with color, you can find the info from **page.getOperatorList()** But to get exact information for which text has which color attributes, you probably has to get map info. Also, **pdf.getOutline()** would give you default info about the color attributes for the whole doc.
**Disclosure:** I haven't worked with PDF.js much apart from few minutes of sample testing last month.

Comment: Can you provide links to a PDF with multi-color text, which can be used for testing solutions?

Comment: http://divillysausages.com/files/pdfjs/testTextColour.pdf - it's a simple pdf created using Open Office, with the words "Hello world", each in a different colour. Is that alright, or do you want something more complex?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As Respawned alluded to, there is no easy answer that will work in all cases. That being said, here are two approaches which seem to work fairly well. Both having upsides and downsides.

## Approach 1

Internally, the `getTextContent` method uses whats called an `EvaluatorPreprocessor` to parse the PDF operators, and maintain the graphic state. So what we can do is, implement a custom `EvaluatorPreprocessor`, overwrite the `preprocessCommand` method, and use it to add the current text color to the graphic state. Once this is in place, anytime a new text chunk is created, we can add a color attribute, and set it to the current color state.

The downsides to this approach are:

1. Requires modifying the PDFJS source code. It also depends heavily on
   the current implementation of PDFJS, and could break if this is
   changed.
2. It will fail in cases where the text is used as a path to be filled with an image. In some PDF creators (such as Photoshop), the way it creates colored text is, it first creates a clipping path from all the given text characters, and then paints a solid image over the path. So the only way to deduce the fill-color is by reading the pixel values from the image, which would require painting it to a canvas. Even hooking into `paintChar` wont be of much help here, since the fill color will only emerge at a later time.

The upside is, its fairly robust and works irrespective of the page background. It also does not require rendering anything to canvas, so it can be done entirely in the background thread.

**Code**

All the modifications are made in the `core/evaluator.js` file.

First you must define the custom evaluator, after the [EvaluatorPreprocessor definition](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/eac168f3cc4df2e8f3f7790c6ca60426b96dcc54/src/core/evaluator.js#L2242).

```
var CustomEvaluatorPreprocessor = (function() {
    function CustomEvaluatorPreprocessor(stream, xref, stateManager, resources) {
        EvaluatorPreprocessor.call(this, stream, xref, stateManager);
        this.resources = resources;
        this.xref = xref;

        // set initial color state
        var state = this.stateManager.state;
        state.textRenderingMode = TextRenderingMode.FILL;
        state.fillColorSpace = ColorSpace.singletons.gray;
        state.fillColor = [0,0,0];
    }

    CustomEvaluatorPreprocessor.prototype = Object.create(EvaluatorPreprocessor.prototype);

    CustomEvaluatorPreprocessor.prototype.preprocessCommand = function(fn, args) {
        EvaluatorPreprocessor.prototype.preprocessCommand.call(this, fn, args);
        var state = this.stateManager.state;
        switch(fn) {
            case OPS.setFillColorSpace:
                state.fillColorSpace = ColorSpace.parse(args[0], this.xref, this.resources);
            break;
            case OPS.setFillColor:
                 var cs = state.fillColorSpace;
                 state.fillColor = cs.getRgb(args, 0);
            break;
            case OPS.setFillGray:
              state.fillColorSpace = ColorSpace.singletons.gray;
              state.fillColor = ColorSpace.singletons.gray.getRgb(args, 0);
            break;
            case OPS.setFillCMYKColor:
              state.fillColorSpace = ColorSpace.singletons.cmyk;
              state.fillColor = ColorSpace.singletons.cmyk.getRgb(args, 0);
            break;
            case OPS.setFillRGBColor:
                state.fillColorSpace = ColorSpace.singletons.rgb;
                state.fillColor = ColorSpace.singletons.rgb.getRgb(args, 0);
            break;
        }
    };

    return CustomEvaluatorPreprocessor;
})();
```

Next, you need to modify the [getTextContent method](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/eac168f3cc4df2e8f3f7790c6ca60426b96dcc54/src/core/evaluator.js#L908) to use the new evaluator:

```
var preprocessor = new CustomEvaluatorPreprocessor(stream, xref, stateManager, resources);
```

And lastly, in the [newTextChunk](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/eac168f3cc4df2e8f3f7790c6ca60426b96dcc54/src/core/evaluator.js#L922) method, add a color attribute:

```
color: stateManager.state.fillColor
```

## Approach 2

Another approach would be to extract the text bounding boxes via `getTextContent`, render the page, and for each text, get the pixel values which reside within its bounds, and take that to be the fill color.

The downsides to this approach are:

1. The computed text bounding boxes are not always correct, and in some cases may even be off completely (eg: rotated text). If the bounding box does not cover at least partially the actual text on canvas, then this method will fail. We can recover from complete failures, by checking that the text pixels have a color variance greater than a threshold. The rationale being, if bounding box is completely background, it will have little variance, in which case we can fallback to a default text color (or maybe even the color of k nearest-neighbors).
2. The method assumes the text is darker than the background. Otherwise, the background could be mistaken as the fill color. This wont be a problem is most cases, as most docs have white backgrounds.

The upside is, its simple, and does not require messing with the PDFJS source-code. Also, it will work in cases where the text is used as a clipping path, and filled with an image. Though this can become hazy when you have complex image fills, in which case, the choice of text color becomes ambiguous.

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/x2rajt5g/

Sample PDF's to test:

- https://www.dropbox.com/s/0t5vtu6qqsdm1d4/color-test.pdf?dl=1
- https://www.dropbox.com/s/cq0067u80o79o7x/testTextColour.pdf?dl=1

**Code**

```
function parseColors(canvasImgData, texts) {
    var data = canvasImgData.data,
        width = canvasImgData.width,
        height = canvasImgData.height,
        defaultColor = [0, 0, 0],
        minVariance = 20;

    texts.forEach(function (t) {
        var left = Math.floor(t.transform[4]),
            w = Math.round(t.width),
            h = Math.round(t.height),
            bottom = Math.round(height - t.transform[5]),
            top = bottom - h,
            start = (left + (top * width)) * 4,
            color = [],
            best = Infinity,
            stat = new ImageStats();

        for (var i, v, row = 0; row < h; row++) {
            i = start + (row * width * 4);
            for (var col = 0; col < w; col++) {
                if ((v = data[i] + data[i + 1] + data[i + 2]) < best) { // the darker the "better"
                    best = v;
                    color[0] = data[i];
                    color[1] = data[i + 1];
                    color[2] = data[i + 2];
                }
                stat.addPixel(data[i], data[i+1], data[i+2]);
                i += 4;
            }
        }
        var stdDev = stat.getStdDev();
        t.color = stdDev < minVariance ? defaultColor : color;
    });
}

function ImageStats() {
    this.pixelCount = 0;
    this.pixels = [];
    this.rgb = [];
    this.mean = 0;
    this.stdDev = 0;
}

ImageStats.prototype = {
    addPixel: function (r, g, b) {
        if (!this.rgb.length) {
            this.rgb[0] = r;
            this.rgb[1] = g;
            this.rgb[2] = b;
        } else {
            this.rgb[0] += r;
            this.rgb[1] += g;
            this.rgb[2] += b;
        }
        this.pixelCount++;
        this.pixels.push([r,g,b]);
    },

    getStdDev: function() {
        var mean = [
            this.rgb[0] / this.pixelCount,
            this.rgb[1] / this.pixelCount,
            this.rgb[2] / this.pixelCount
        ];
        var diff = [0,0,0];
        this.pixels.forEach(function(p) {
            diff[0] += Math.pow(mean[0] - p[0], 2);
            diff[1] += Math.pow(mean[1] - p[1], 2);
            diff[2] += Math.pow(mean[2] - p[2], 2);
        });
        diff[0] = Math.sqrt(diff[0] / this.pixelCount);
        diff[1] = Math.sqrt(diff[1] / this.pixelCount);
        diff[2] = Math.sqrt(diff[2] / this.pixelCount);
        return diff[0] + diff[1] + diff[2];
    }
};
```

Comment: Holy hell, this is amazing work; it makes me want to be able to upvote you more than once. Quickly testing the second approach is working out well so far, thanks!

Comment: This surely gets my vote for being more detailed. I would however caution against overselling the 2nd method as always (or  often) working for clipping paths because there may anything underneath, [e.g. an arbitrary image](http://www.pdflib.com/fileadmin/pdflib/Cookbook/pdf/text_as_clipping_path.pdf), for which the notion of (a single) fill color isn't particularly well defined. I'm not seeing why someone (or some program) would generate text clipping paths over a solid color when it's cheaper computationally to use fill. A clipping path is typically used in nasty cases like the one I linked.

Comment: The Photoshop-made PDF contains [this image](http://imgur.com/676lg6i) painted over the clipping path of the text. A similar looking PDF (same text & with the same font embedded) produced in Inkscape has only 12KB vs. Photoshop's 86KB so it doesn't look smart size-wise. Photoshop also draws the characters one by one (Tj), not with array commands (TJ) and also does a move transform (Tm) for each letter instead of each line. So writing a lot of PDF text in Photoshop doesn't look like a good idea. Inkscape does the usual fill procedure with the font colors (no images).

Comment: The differing `text rendering modes` indeed makes things tricky and  ambiguous. Say in the case of black text with a white stroke (on a black background), what color is the text? or in the case of an image pattern fill, what is the text color? In the latter, I think sampling a color within it, is still "better" than reporting nothing. My assumption is, for image-like text (strokes, image-fills etc), the user would not so much be interested in parsing the colors, due to the inherent ambiguities. In these cases, the distinction between image and text becomes blurred (eg: a textual logo).

Comment: It is surprising how inefficiently Photoshop generates PDF's. I certainly don't suggest using it for PDF creation. However, when parsing arbitrary PDF's, you don't get to make that choice. In practice, it may very well be that Photoshop is rarely used for PDF creation, but I don't know.

Comment: @levi: Yes, the 2nd solution tricks PDFJS into doing more work for us for this problem, i.e. color composition. I also think the incorrect bounding box for rotated (or other path) text is a bug in PDFJS that should be reported. With the 2nd approach, you could also do something statistical, like average every non-background color pixel in the bounding box to arrive at an average fill color, etc. N.B.: I've transferred the 100 bounty points I've received from divillysausages to you. I'm sure that had you posted your answer before his bounty deadlined, he would have wanted you to have it.

Comment: You can even do background vs. foreground detection that (statistical) way, which would work for simple reversed color. Compute a histogram counting every pixel color you in the bounding box, then take the highest-count value as the background (assumed uniform) and the next highest as the foreground/fill (also assumed uniform). The underlying assumption here is that most fonts are relatively "thin" so in a bounding box you'll get more background color pixels than fill/foreground color. The average amount of black in a B&W text page is typically estimated at 5% by printer manufacturers.

Comment: And regarding Photoshops' choice of PDF output: I think it's optimized for a different use case as the common one, which differs from the common use case of OpenOffice, Inkscape or XELATEX (I tried the latter too in the meantime, and the output is pretty much like Inkscape's). I think Photoshop, being mainly a raster-image program, assumes you won't have a lot of text in your output but that you'll have a lot of color variation across the page, possibly with every pixel being a different color. I think that's why it computes and then stores in the PFD that background image layer.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff The rotated bounding boxes should indeed be improved. But this will still not fix all cases of misaligned bounding-boxes. Some old docs have a single image containing the text, and then overlay transparent text on top for text selection/searching. In these cases the bounds are often way off. Averaging the "non-white" colors was my initial approach. The problem with this was, smooth text has lighter edges and and only a small percent of the painted glyph is the darkest (actual color). This leads to an average which is much lighter than desired. Thanks for that.

Comment: @levi: Good point regarding averaging. I had indeed overlooked the impact of font anti-aliasing (which most web browsers normally employ) on this text-color determination problem. In computer vision this is called the [image matting problem](http://www.computervisiononline.com/books/computer-vision/image-matting) and is a fairly tough one.

Comment: The histogram is an interesting idea. As you say it requires a uniform background, which means a slightly textured background could throw it off. I am also a bit unsure that the background will always be greater than foreground. What about a lowercase "i"? This also runs into the issue of thin text having more edges than body. [See here](http://i.imgur.com/quxirr4.png?1)

Answer (score 6):

This question is actually extremely hard if you want to do it to perfection... or it can be relatively easy if you can live with solutions that work only some of the time.

First of all, realize that `getTextContent` is intended for searchable text extraction and that's all it's intended to do.

It's been suggested in the comments above that you use `page.getOperatorList()`, but that's basically re-implementing the whole PDF drawing model in your code... which is basically silly because the largest chunk of PDFJS does exactly that... except not for the purpose of text extraction but for the purpose of rendering to canvas. So what you want to do is to hack [canvas.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/canvas.js) so that instead of just setting its internal knobs it also does some callbacks to your code. Alas, if you go this way, you won't be able to use stock PDFJS, and I rather doubt that your goal of color extraction will be seen as very useful for PDFJS' main purpose, so your changes are likely not going to get accepted upstream, so you'll likely have to maintain your own fork of PDFJS.

After this dire warning, what you'd need to minimally change are the functions where PDFJS has parsed the PDF color operators and sets its own canvas painting color. That happens around line 1566 (of canvas.js) in [function setFillColorN](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/e7cddcce283c5e76bc042747b5588a6d250c25e1/src/display/canvas.js#L1664). You'll also need to hook the text render... which is rather a character renderer at canvas.js level, namely [CanvasGraphics_paintChar](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/e7cddcce283c5e76bc042747b5588a6d250c25e1/src/display/canvas.js#L1350) around line 1270. With these two hooked, you'll get a stream of callbacks for color changes interspersed between character drawing sequences. So you can reconstruct the color of character sequences reasonably easy from this.. in the simple color cases.

And now I'm getting to the really ugly part: the fact that PDF has an extremely complex color model. First there are two colors for drawing anything, including text: a fill color and stroke (outline) color. So far not too scary, but the color is an index in a ColorSpace... of which there are several, RGB being only one possibility. Then there's also alpha and compositing modes, so the layers (of various alphas) can result in a different final color depending on the compositing mode. And the PDFJS has not a single place where it accumulates color from layers.. it simply [over]paints them as they come. So if you only extract the fill color changes and ignore alpha, compositing etc.. it will work but not for complex documents.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that; I guess my knowledge of PDF rendering is going to need a major boost :D. I'll look into hooking into `_paintChar()` - it's for a quick project so it doesn't need to be particularly tidy or maintainable

Answer (score 2):

During the process of developing PDF document translation, I finally found a relatively reasonable solution because I needed to use text color.

For more details, can refer to [PDF Transaction — How to extract the text information of a PDF?](https://medium.com/@loger.zhu/pdf-transaction-how-to-use-pdf-js-b669f092fc1d)

In general, it just need to following the PDF's operation to locate the position of the corresponding text and then retrieve the current color from the current image state.

```
export function getItemColor(item: TextItem, operatorList: PDFOperatorList) {
  // Stack for recording states
  const stack: PDFStatus[] = []
  // Current state record
  let currentStatus: PDFStatus = {}
  
  //  Analyze the page instructions in order
  for (let fnIndex = 0; fnIndex < operatorList.fnArray.length; fnIndex++) {
    const fn = operatorList.fnArray[fnIndex]
    const args = operatorList.argsArray[fnIndex]
    switch (fn) {
      //push currentStatus to stack
      case OPS.save:
        stack.push(currentStatus)
        currentStatus = { ...currentStatus }
        break
      //restore currentStatus from stack
      case OPS.restore:
        currentStatus = stack.pop() ?? {}
        break
      //Set text fill color
      case OPS.setFillRGBColor:
        currentStatus.currentColor = [args[0], args[1], args[2]]
        break
      //Set text area
      case OPS.setTextMatrix:
        currentStatus.currentMatrix = [args[4], args[5]]
        currentStatus.currentXY = [args[4], args[5]]
        break
      //Set line spacing
      case OPS.setLeading:
        currentStatus.leading = args[0]
        break
      //Set font type and size
      case OPS.setFont:
        currentStatus.font = [args[0], args[1]]
        break
      //Calculate line break, when line break occurs, the current coordinates need to jump to the beginning of the next line
      case OPS.nextLine:
      case OPS.nextLineShowText:
      case OPS.nextLineSetSpacingShowText:
        if (currentStatus.leading && currentStatus.currentXY) {
          currentStatus.currentXY = [currentStatus.currentXY[0], currentStatus.currentXY[1] - currentStatus.leading]
        }
        break
      // Move text coordinates
      case OPS.moveText:
        if (currentStatus.currentXY) {
          currentStatus.currentXY = [currentStatus.currentXY[0] + args[0], currentStatus.currentXY[1] + args[1]]
        }
        break
      //Show text
      case OPS.showText:
        if (currentStatus.currentXY) {
          let x = currentStatus.currentXY[0]
          let y = currentStatus.currentXY[1]
          // Check if the text matches the position
          const isMatch = () =>
            Math.abs(x - item.transform[4]) < item.height / 5 && Math.abs(y - item.transform[5]) < item.height / 5
          if (isMatch()) {
            return currentStatus.currentColor
          }
          if (args[0]) {
            // Calculate the actual coordinates of each printed character, and then match them with the coordinates of the item
            for (let charInfo of args[0]) {
              if (typeof charInfo?. width == 'number' && currentStatus.font) {
                if (isMatch()) {
                  return currentStatus.currentColor
                }
                x += (charInfo?. width / 1000) * currentStatus.font[1]
              } else if (typeof charInfo == 'number' && currentStatus.font) {
                if (isMatch()) {
                  return currentStatus.currentColor
                }
                x -= (charInfo / 1000) * currentStatus.font[1]
              }
            }
          }
        }
        break
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to patch pdfjs, the transform property gives the x and y, so you can go through the operator list and find the setFillColor op that precedes the text op at that point.

Answer (score 0):

## Updates to 'Approach 1' of the Answer by levi

Recently I've also wanted to get the text color information from a PDF. levi's approaches really help.  Approach 1 can be used with nodejs, so that's my choice.

Now that I'm using **PDFJS v2.16**, it seems certain updates to the original solution are necessary. I've tried and so share here.

What's new with PDFJS v2.16:

- The function `ColorSpace.parse` has changed its parameters, so the original `ColorSpace.parse(args[0], this.xref, this.resources)` is no longer valid and would cause errors/warnings.
- The function prototype style of creating the class `CustomEvaluatorPreprocessor` is no longer appropriate. Use the modern class instead.

Code Updates:

Note that here I will only introduce the changes relative to the original answer.

1. The definition of the custom evaluator:

```js
class CustomEvaluatorPreprocessor extends EvaluatorPreprocessor {
  constructor(stream, xref, stateManager, resources, pdfFunctionFactory) {
    super(stream, xref, stateManager);
    this.resources = resources;
    this.xref = xref;
    this.pdfFunctionFactory = pdfFunctionFactory;

    // set initial color state
    const state = this.stateManager.state;
    state.textRenderingMode = TextRenderingMode.FILL;
    state.fillColorSpace = ColorSpace.singletons.gray;
    state.fillColor = [0, 0, 0];
  }
  preprocessCommand(fn, args) {
    super.preprocessCommand(fn, args);
    const state = this.stateManager.state;
    const localColorSpaceCache = new LocalColorSpaceCache();
    switch (fn) {
      case OPS.setFillColorSpace:
        state.fillColorSpace = ColorSpace.parse({
          cs: args[0], 
          xref: this.xref, 
          resources: this.resources,
          pdfFunctionFactory: this.pdfFunctionFactory,
          localColorSpaceCache
        });
        break;
      case OPS.setFillColor:
        const cs = state.fillColorSpace;
        state.fillColor = cs.getRgb(args, 0);
        break;
      case OPS.setFillGray:
        state.fillColorSpace = ColorSpace.singletons.gray;
        state.fillColor = ColorSpace.singletons.gray.getRgb(args, 0);
        break;
      case OPS.setFillCMYKColor:
        state.fillColorSpace = ColorSpace.singletons.cmyk;
        state.fillColor = ColorSpace.singletons.cmyk.getRgb(args, 0);
        break;
      case OPS.setFillRGBColor:
        state.fillColorSpace = ColorSpace.singletons.rgb;
        state.fillColor = ColorSpace.singletons.rgb.getRgb(args, 0);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

2. Use the new evaluator:

```js
const preprocessor = new CustomEvaluatorPreprocessor(stream, xref, stateManager, resources, this._pdfFunctionFactory);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just some long comments on above comments, that sample is actually very easy to show why some files can be so problematic to reverse engineer.

So I see it is the most basic case which should be easy to follow when the reader decompresses the content. Here is the challenge the file at its core has 2 objects

- 1 is the page definition
- 2 is the content
- 9 is the /F1 character font  (defined in Resources 11)

```
%PDF-1.4
%ÂµÂ¶

1 0 obj
<</Type/Page/Parent 4 0 R/Resources 11 0 R/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]/Group<</S/Transparency/CS/DeviceRGB/I true>>/Contents 2 0 R>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<</Length 176>>
stream
0.1 w
q 0 0.1 595.2 841.8 re
W* n
q 0 0 0 rg
BT
56.8 774.1 Td /F1 12 Tf[<01>-2<02>1<03>2<03>2<0405>]TJ
ET
Q
q 1 0 0 rg
BT
86.5 774.1 Td /F1 12 Tf[<06>-2<040703>2<08>]TJ
ET
Q
Q 
endstream
endobj
```

Thus knowing the content is Hello world from the visual look-up we can see

- A) the Page says the colours will be /DeviceRGB (but there could be other Graphic States)
- B) all page components will be unknown colour until the component colour is changed thus after `q 0 0 0 rg` any component will be BLACK and the first component after that is a TEXT STRING ENCODED `01 02 03 03 04 05` thus clearly the "Transposition/permutation cipher" (Not the Roman Times one by Caesar) every schoolboy would use for `Hello`  (note that the space character is included in the BLACK)
- C) now the black pen is replaced with a RED one `q 1 0 0 rg` and more text is written `06 04 07 03 08` (so the most common character `03` is easily see as the `l` as in what the `Hell` shows, and `o`=04 too)

Now this file is the simplest case of 8 coded characters that can be understood very easily but there are many more complex cases where it is not so simple to detect the sequence until after display, thus a good GUI or full Command line TRACE or convert to simpler HTML can help.

Thus conversion to HTML as done by PDF.JS will give you a Y alternative output to the real X problem itself.

[image]